# How do i pass a string as payload to aws lambda function using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to use the below aws cli command to invoke the lambda function.

```
aws lambda invoke  --invocation-type RequestResponse  --function-name HelloWorldJava  --payload \"world\" outputfile.txt
```

But Iam getting below error.

```
Invalid base64: ""world""
```

The book I am referring to is using the same method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your payload has to be JSON according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#options), but I think there is no hard requirement for that. When you want to pass in a string value directly (JSON or otherwise) you also need to be sure that you pass [`--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out`.](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cli-invalid-base64-lambda-error)

So you command should be:

```bash
aws lambda invoke  --invocation-type RequestResponse  --function-name HelloWorldJava --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload \"world\" outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Configurations**

- Mac OS
- VS code

## **Error**

`--payload`

> The JSON that you want to provide to your Lambda function as input.
>
> You can enter the JSON directly. For example, `--payload '{ "key": "value" }'` . You can also specify a file path. For example, `--payload file://payload.json` .

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#options)

## **Correction**

you need to clarify with this command:

```
--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
```

## **Method**

Here is the correct syntax:

```
aws lambda invoke \
> --invocation-type RequestResponse \
> --function-name HelloWorldJava \
> --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
> --payload \"world\" outputfile.txt
```

Run your code again

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass payload as a json-string - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#examples

> --payload (blob)
>
> The JSON that you want to provide to your Lambda function as input.
>
> You can enter the JSON directly. For example, --payload '{ "key":
> "value" }' . You can also specify a file path. For example, --payload
> file://payload.json .

```
aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name my-function \
    --payload '{ "name": "Bob" }' \
    response.json
```